# Passing a field variable of one class as argument to creation of another class object?

Tags: java

I have a question regarding the passing of a instance variable as an argument to a new object being created. In the second class, it seems to be modifying the field member of the first class, which I didn't think was the case. I'll post a little code that shows what I mean -

```
    private void movethePiece(int whichToMove) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Mover theMover = new Mover(whichToMove, positions); // positions is an array
    //and is an instance variable in the current class.
```

Now here's the constructor in the class mover -

```
    public class Mover {
    private int toMove;
    private int[] posArray;
    private Boolean toSwap;

    public Mover(int tilePiece, int[] positions) {
        toMove = tilePiece;
        posArray = new int[16];
        posArray = positions; //assigning positions to a new variable
        toSwap = false
}
```

The code is modifying positions in the first class. If I didn't want it to do so, would I have to create a new object in the first class with the array values of positions and pass it instead? I figured since I created a new int[] in the mover class, that would take care of it being directly modified.

Answer (score 1):

I think your understanding is close, but you are misunderstanding one concept. When you write:

```
posArray = new int[16];
posArray = positions;
```

You are first creating a new object (`int[]`), but the pointer pointing to this object is then set to be *pointing to an existing object*. In Java, arrays are objects on the heap, and you can have multiple references pointing to the same object. Any changes to the array through any reference reflects for all references. To get around this in a simple case, you need to `clone` your array before passing it in.

```
Mover theMover = new Mover(whichToMove, positions.clone());
```

Comment: Generally, better to stay off `clone()` (advised in 'Effective Java'). One can use pair of `new int[src.length]; System.arraycopy(...);` for primitive types instead. For reference types you'll need explicit 'copy constructor'.

Comment: @VictorSorokin Interesting, didn't know that clone wasn't advisable. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: Thank you guys! Appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
posArray = new int[16];
posArray = positions;
```

do this:

```
posArray = Arrays.copyOf(positions, 16);
```

This will effectively copy the *contents* of your `positions` array into `posArray`.

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the feedback!